X axis not showing on d3 graph
Hello I'm currently creating a line chart that takes in as x values the seconds in my .csv file and takes in as y values the value of the signal that represents a patients electrodermal activity.
I've followed the d3 code from this page https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_basic.html but for some reason the g element representing x-axis does not show even when appended to the svg element
I'm using react with d3 so svg variable is a reference to the svg element i'm rendering here is my code:
useEffect(() => {
        console.log("state updated");
        console.log(sprSheet);

        if(sprSheet.length != 0){
            let max_signal = d3.max(sprSheet, (row) => row['raw_signal']);
            let min_signal = d3.min(sprSheet, (row) => row['raw_signal']);
            let min_sec = sprSheet[0]['time'];
            let max_sec = sprSheet[sprSheet.length - 1]['time'];

            console.log(`max signal: ${max_signal}`);
            console.log(`min_signal: ${min_signal}`);
            console.log(`max_sec: ${max_sec}`);
            console.log(`min_sec: ${min_sec}`);

            // const width = 'clamp(500px, 75vw, 1260px)';
            // const height = '250px';
            const margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60, }
            const width = 1024 - margin["left"] - margin["right"];
            const height = 512 - margin["top"] - margin["bottom"]; 

            // recall translate takes in x and y coordinates of how much
            // to move the element along the x and y axis respectively
            const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current)
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right) // still is 768 since we add back the subtracted values from margin top and margin bottom
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom) // still is 486 since we add back the subtracted values from margin top and margin bottom
            // .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width * 1.5, height * 1.5])
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "cartesian-plane")
            .attr("transform", `translate(${margin["left"]}, ${margin["top"]})`); // this is the g element which draws the line

            // x here is a callback function
            let x = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain([min_sec, max_sec])
            .range([0, width]);

            // we create a g element which will draw the x-axis
            svg.append('g')
            .attr("class", "x-axis")
            .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
            .call(d3.axisBottom);
            
            // y here is also callback function
            let y = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain([0, max_signal])
            .range([height, 0]);

            // we create a g element which will draw the y-axis
            svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y-axis")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
      
            // Set the gradient
            svg.append("linearGradient")
            .attr("class", "line-gradient")
            .attr("id", "line-gradient")
            .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
            .attr("x1", 0)
            .attr("y1", y(0))
            .attr("x2", 0)
            .attr("y2", y(max_signal))
            .selectAll("stop")
            .data([
                {offset: "0%", color: "#c78324"},
                {offset: "50%", color: "#ab229d"},
                {offset: "100%", color: "#2823ba"}
            ])
            .enter().append("stop")
            .attr("offset", (d) => d["offset"])
            .attr("stop-color", (d) => d["color"]);
      
            // Add the line
            svg.append("path")
            .datum(sprSheet)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "url(#line-gradient)" )
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("d", d3.line()
                .x((d) => x(d['time']))
                .y((d) => y(d['raw_signal']))
            )

        }else{

            console.log('spreadsheet input mounted');
        }

Here's also a picture of how the react app renders the d3 graph:


You didn’t pass a scale to d3.axisBottom like you do for d3.axisLeft
